# How to calculate the SUM of time in hh:mi format in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, time

I have a pandas data frame like this:

[image]

how can i calculate the SUM of total time per group? the time format is in HH:MI.
for example for G1 we've total (01:30+02:30+05:30)=09:30.
I've checked many solutions like separating each item via ":" by for loop or multiplying it *60 but no success.

Comment: easier if shared as text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert each value to `Timedelta` than sum them:

```
df['SUM'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['HOURS'].str.split(',').explode() + [':00']) \
              .groupby(level=0).sum()
print(df)

# Output
  GROUP              HOURS             SUM
0    G1  01:30,02:30,05:30 0 days 09:30:00
1    G2  02:30,05:30,07:30 0 days 15:30:00
```